# Creating files on the fly and converting to pdf

Tags: python, file-io, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to create a html file and then convert this file to a pdf file using `wkhtmltopdf` http://wkhtmltopdf.org/

```
inputfilename = "/tmp/inputfile.html" 
outputfilename = "/tmp/outputfile.pdf"
f = open(inputfilename, 'w')
f.write(html)
f.close()
f1 =  open(outputfilename, 'w')    
ret = convert2pdf(f,outputfilename) 
f1.close()
```

In convert2pdf I'm doing:

`def convert2pdf(htmlfilename,outputpdf):
    import subprocess
    commands_to_run  = ['/wkhtmltopdf-amd64','htmlfilename', 'outputpdf']
    subprocess.call(commands_to_run)`

Both input/output files are created on the fly. Input file is perfect but output pdf created using `wkhtmltopdf` is empty. Can you suggest what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Just curious, why are you opening f1 and then closing it? It would seem your Python program has a the output file open for writing while you are trying to write to the same file using an external process.

Comment: If I don't open and close it the pdf is not being generated. Ideally wkhtmltopdf creates a new pdf if you give it a html file but in this case it's not.
sample command to make a pdf using wkhtmltopdf: `wkhtmltopdf my.html my.pdf`

Comment: You don't need to (and some would argue shouldn't) open f1 at all in your python code.

Comment: Yes you are right @doogabides. Problem was somewhere else. I removed f1.open and close its still working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just have to change

```
commands_to_run = ['/wkhtmltopdf-amd64','htmlfilename', 'outputpdf']
```

to

```
commands_to_run = ['/wkhtmltopdf-amd64', htmlfilename, outputpdf]
```

and instead of

```
ret = convert2pdf(f,outputfilename)
```

do

```
ret = convert2pdf(inputfilename, outputfilename)
```

Comment: Oh man...this worked. Thanks a lot. Was stuck on this for 2 hours. But tell me in `commands_to_run` why we have give without quotes. suppose we want to run the command `ls` we do `subprocess.call(['ls'])` there we use quotes in `ls`. why not here?

Comment: Just because you asked - the quotes are not needed for htmlfilename and outputpdf because those are not the actual filenames - those are variables (object names really) that contain that real filenames. So they don't get quotes because you are doing variable substitution.